# camel cxf giving error when sending large xml

Tags: apache-camel, soap-client, jbossfuse

When calling a SOAP service I am getting response 302 when the XML message size is large but works when the message size is small.
Though when I post the same message on a SoapUI I am getting a correct response for both small and large messages.

Is there a limit to message length in camel cxf, if yes?
How can I change the limit?

Camel 2.10
JBoss Fuse 6.0.0

This the extract of my cxfEndpoint

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="remindaWsEndpoint" address="https://example.service.abc.com/BasicService"
    serviceName="s:ABCService"
    endpointName="s:ABCHttpBinding_ABCService"
    wsdlURL="/META-INF/wsdl/ABCService.wsdl"
    xmlns:s="http://www.example.com">
    <cxf:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor" />
    </cxf:outInterceptors>
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor"/>
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD" />
        <entry key="allowStreaming" value="true" />
        <entry key="defaultOperationName" value="ABCOperations"/>
        <entry key="defaultOperationNamespace" value="http://www.example.com"/>
    </cxf:properties>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 302 is not an error. It means the server is trying to redirect you to another url. Ensure your route configuration can handle that.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302

Comment: Souciance, yes sorry for framing the question wrongly. Issue still remain as why it works for small message size and fails for larger one. Though the bigger message still work using SoapUI.